# Why has linking a .Net 4.7.2 console program to a .Net Standard 2.0 library resulted in dotnet seeking an old JSON library?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, .net-standard

I've built a .net standard 2.0 library that I'm using for a cross platform project.  For testing, I've created two console projects which use both .Net 7 and .Net 4.7.2 (Framework) to link to it.

Both work fine in Visual studio and I can get the .Net 7 one working fine on a VM.  However, getting the .Net 4.7.2 one working has resulted in some kind of odd dependency hell.

When I run the program, I get this:

```
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Ben/Desktop/472/System.Text.Json.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
'. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationSerializer.Read(String json, OpenIdConnectConfiguration config)
```

The dll in the `Desktop\472` folder is the 6.0 version of `System.Text.Json.dll`.  And the `.netstandard 2.0` library calls for that version in it's dependencies:

[image]

So, I simply don't understand why, at runtime on a VM, the 4.0.1.2 version of the library would be sought..  It's as if it's trying to load the version associated .Net framework even though all those libraries have come from the .netstandard project.

The only thing the 4.7.2 console project links to is the bare system libs and the `.netstandard 2.0 project`.  So this dependency seems to be unlisted anywhere...

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Perhaps [NuGet Solver](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-nugetsolver-a-powerful-tool-for-resolving-nuget-dependency-conflicts-in-visual-studio/) may help to diagnose the issue?

Comment: What does the .csproj file for the .Net 4.7.2 one look like? (Also, have you considered multitargeting the console app to .NET 7 AND .Net 4.7.2 - although you should fix the issue before attempting that...)

Comment: (Also note that .NET 7 will no longer be supported in 3 month's time!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson It seems like multi-targeting was the solution.  Cheers for the suggestion.